# JDBC Connection taking too long

Tags: java, spring-mvc, jdbc

I have an issue in my Spring MVC JDBC call. If I make the call quickly after starting the server, the JDBC connection is make in a second and the data is retrieved. Similarly, if the other DAOs are called in quick succession with one another, the connection is made soon. But if I try to call a DAO after a gap of even a few minutes, the JDBC connection takes forever to be done. It gets stuck on

> "DataSourceUtils:110 - Fetching JDBC Connection from DataSource"

I have never had the patience to really check how long it takes to retrieve the connection but I've waited for 10 minutes and there was no sign of the connection being made.

Next, I try to restart the server at least. But JDBC obstructs even stopping of the server!! The console is stuck on this line:

> "DisposableBeanAdapter:327 - Invoking destroy method 'close' on bean with name 'dataSource'"

Eventually I restart Eclipse and it works alright until there is a time gap again.

This is my bean definition for the data source:

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
        destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
    <property name="url" value="url" />
    <property name="username" value="abc" />
    <property name="password" value="abc" />
    <property name="validationQuery" value="SELECT 1" />
    <property name="testWhileIdle" value="true" />
    <property name="maxActive" value="100" />
    <property name="minIdle" value="10" />
    <property name="initialSize" value="10" />
    <property name="maxIdle" value="20" />
    <property name="maxWait" value="1000" />
</bean>

<bean id="jdbcTemplate" class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
</bean>

<bean id="getDataDao" class="com.project.dao.GetDataDao">
    <constructor-arg index="0" ref="jdbcTemplate" />
    <constructor-arg index="1" value="STORED_PROC_NAME"></constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

In my DAO file, I extend Spring's StoredProcedure class and this is the constructor:

```
public GetDataDao(JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate, String spName) {

        super(jdbcTemplate, spName);

        declareParameter(new SqlParameter("p_input", Types.VARCHAR));
        declareParameter(new SqlOutParameter("o_result", Types.VARCHAR));

        compile();
    }
```

In another function, this is how I call the SP:

```
spOutput = super.execute(spInput);
```

where `spOutput` and `spInput` are HashMaps.

Am I doing something wrong in my configuration? TIA.

Comment: Not in your configuration, I suspect in your code... Don't get connections yourself and use spring managed transactions. If yuo don't your pool will eventually run out of available connections. In your case after about 100 requests (unless you configured MySQL to disallow those connections).

Comment: Eclipse has nothing to do with this.  I never understand why people mention their IDE when they have problems.  Spring does this correctly every day in my apps; it's something in your code.

Comment: Modify your question and post the code where you get and use the connection.

Comment: @M.Deinum, that sounds possible. How could I check if MySQL is configured to have such a timeout? I use PHPMyAdmin for MySQL.

Comment: @duffymo could you share a snippet please? I think Eclipse is relevant here because that's where I'm handling my tomcat server from.

Comment: @kaliatech, what code would be relevant here? I'll add that. 

As of now, this data source bean is sent to the DAO classes as a constructor argument.

Comment: I doubt that Eclipse is relevant.  You can prove it by shutting down Eclipse, deploying your WAR on Tomcat locally, and starting it up.  If the behavior persists, then Eclipse is not involved.

Comment: @duffymo Oh in that sense I'm sure Eclipse isn't the issue here. I just mentioned it to explain how I get over the issue. The issue persists even when it is deployed locally outside eclipse.

Comment: Exactly my point.  Eclipse is not pertinent.

Comment: Post an example of one of your DAO methods then. You mention that you pass Datasource constructor argument. Show code where you then use that datasource. A potential cause of your problem is that connections are not being correctly closed and returned to the pool.

Comment: @kaliatech, I've added more code. Please let me know if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I too had the exact same issue. I found that issue was consistent with a particular query,  checked the query and found that issue was within query itself. Running query separately was also taking time.  Query was converting a column to lower and that column was not indexed.  Query was like lower(trim(column_name)), removed the lower and trim. It worked perfectly fine after that.

Answer (score -1):

The additional code helps, but I do not see anything in it that would cause issue you are seeing. The most likely reason for issue you are seeing is that connections are being pulled out of the pool, but they are not being returned, and the pool eventually becomes starved. The dbcp pool is then later blocking your shutdown because these connections are still open, and probably hung.

To verify, you might try setting maxActive and similar settings to something much lower, perhaps even "1", and then verify that you get the same issue immediately.

Have you verified that your stored procedure is returning? i.e. You actually get `spOutput` for every call and the stored procedure itself is not hanging consistently or randomly?

If so, my only other suggestion is to post more code, especially from the call stack leading in to `GetDataDao`, and including whatever method in the DAO is making the sp.execute call. An assumption is that you are not using transactions, but if you are, then showing where you start/commit transaction in code would also be very important.

Comment: `spOutput` does return data correctly. It only hangs when getting the connection. Once that's established the SP executed quickly and the data is retreived. I don't think they rest of the code is relevant. It has nothing to do with the JDBC connection.

Comment: @javaGirl243 - I didn't downvote you, but would assume it's because your question is not clear, and does not contain enough information in for someone to truly help you.  Similarly, my answer was downvoted probably because I did not provide a succinct answer, and the downvoter did not think your question should've been answered.  Would suggest posting a new question, but keeping it concise and showing the missing code I mentioned in in my answer. StackOverflow is not always a friendly place to newcomers, but still, the intent is to maintain a certain quality of questions and answers.

Comment: If you decide to post a new question, consider deleting this one.